# Dependent Variable in Factor Analysis. How to measure attitude toward application usage?

Tags: regression, factor-analysis, research-design, explanatory-models

I am performing an analysis to evaluate the attitude of our marketers toward Apps. I have done the explanatory factor analysis (principal component)and I have received 4 factors (one of my factors is attitude towards app), however I understood that it is not possible to run a regression of the other 3 factors on the dependent variable. What should I do? How can I determine the effect of variables on attitude toward app?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Factor analysis doesn't typically have a dependent variable (well, they're all dependent).